# Fastlane not initializing environment variables --env

Tags: ios, xcode, environment, fastlane

I am using fastlane for my iOS application. In this case I have an xcode project with multiple targets. Therefor I want to use some different variables in fastlane. However the variables are not initialized.

I have set up custom .env files for each target. For example the .env file of Target1:

```
ENV_TARGET_NAME=MyAppName
ENV_TARGET_NAME_SHORT=MyAppNameShort
```

The .env file is called .env.Target1 and is set in the fastlane folder. I already tried to see if this is working by placing the file in the root folder of my project.

My fastlane files looks like the following:

```
fastlane_version "1.109.0"

before_all do
     ensure_git_status_clean
     skip_docs
end

lane :QA_all do
    sh "fastlane QA --env Target1"
    sh "fastlane QA --env Target2"
    sh "fastlane QA --env Target3"
end

lane :accept_all do
    sh "fastlane QA --env Target1"
    sh "fastlane QA --env Target2"
    sh "fastlane QA --env Target3"
end

lane :live_all do
    sh "fastlane QA --env Target1"
    sh "fastlane QA --env Target2"
    sh "fastlane QA --env Target3"
end

desc "Builing version with TEST environment"
lane :QA do |options|
    target_name = ENV['ENV_TARGET_NAME']


/* Rest of the file */
```

-- Update

Using 
    options[:target_name] 
is getting the target name. However I am sending this to a .sh file to move to the ipa to the correct folder.

```
sh "sh ./scripts/ipa_deployment.sh #{version_number} #{target_name}
```

When I set the target_name hardcoded like "MyAppName" I will see the variable inside the .sh file. However when I set it from the options[:target_name] the variable is empty. Someone any idea why this is happening?

Comment: I don't really understand what your goal is, but it would seem to me that you should just call the `:QA` lane with the options you want. For example,
`lane :QA_all do
  QA { target_name: Target1 }
  QA { target_name: Target2 }
  QA { target_name: Target3 }
end

lane :QA do |options|
  puts "do whatever you want with #{options[:target_name}"
end`

Comment: My goal is to use the target name from the application to write the .ipa to a folder depending on this value. So each target puts the .ipa file in a folder named as the target. My code works when I set the target_name hardcoded but is not getting the value out of the environment file.

As I understand It would be possible to use something like 

    `#{options[:target_name}` to get the target name?

I will try it out and comment here again

Comment: BTW, I mis-typed how to do this, to get the option in the code, you need only `options[:target_name]`. The `#{options[:target_name]}` is to get it in the Ruby string.

Comment: I think that it's better way if you create **.env** file for each target (**.env.Target1**, **.env.Target2**). 
Then u can use `fastlane <lane-name> --env Target1`,  `fastlane <lane-name> --env Target2` ...

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it wrong.
As documentation says https://docs.fastlane.tools/advanced/#environment-variables
It's loads first `.env` and then your `.env.myTarget`

But look what are you doing, your run `fastlane QA_all` (f.ex.) This instance of fastlane has no `env` at all! That's why you are having an empty string.

Even, when you are doing `sh ...` this will run on another, I'm not sure, process?¿?, the output will not be the same as which you started fastlane.

If you want to run 3 construction / deploy scripts for 3 differents Targets (Apps I understand). You should go better for a script where you call your 3 fastlane configurations.

I have not tried, but should be serialized on the script, launching your first fastlane Target1, and when it's finished, running the 2 and so on... but better test this.

I hope this will help you ;).